# Object reference not set to an instance of an object., getting error on partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Hi I am getting this error while loading a partial view

> Line 27: @foreach (var item in Model)

the stack trace is:

> [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
>          ASP._Page_Views_ServiceRevenue__ServicePartial_cshtml.Execute() in f:\Guri_Projects\DM\DM\Views\ServiceRevenue_ServicePartial.cshtml:27
>          System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +197
>          System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +105

partial view start with:

```
@model IEnumerable<DM.Models.DB.ServiceWiseRevenue>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
```

Comment: Make sure that your Model isn't null.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: You have not passed a model to the view so your model is `null` - hence the exception. Read the duplicate carefully to understand how to debug your code.

Comment: But i already added Model in top line as already mentioned. When i remove Ienumerable it is workin for one column only but thrown error with Ienumerable.

Answer (score 0):

i was passing the null value to View. Now it is resolved as i put some condition in controller before returning partial view. Thanks